# How to add onclick functions in an array of buttons using a for loop properly?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a kind of HTML calculator to test something I have in mind.
I've used a for loop to create the buttons of the keypad. The display is a text field.
Then I used a for loop to add the functions in the buttons:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    buttons[i].onclick = function()
    {
        display.value += i;
    };
}
```

What I was trying to do is to make, for example, buttons[0] add "0" to the value of the text field when clicked. Instead, clicking any button added "10" in the text field. Why? How can I make it right?

Comment: show us your full code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: There really is no need to. This is the only snippet that needs to be changed and the rest of the code doesn't affect it. Buttons are of input type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right , you just need to change `var` to `let` in your loop declaration :

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    buttons[i].onclick = function()
    {
        display.value += i;
    };
}
```

[What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) Here  you can  get more info about your issue.

Comment: The solution actually worked by using Google Chrome instead of Edge, which I've resorted to using for several reasons.
Which means that Edge doesn't support let?

Comment: Sure! But what if I want to use Edge? This solution doesn't work with Edge or IE.

Comment: @Bluberry17 it's hard to say why it didn't work in Edge, there can be a lot of reasons. I'm not sure if i can help you with that. Checking   developer console for errors would be my best guess in this case.

Comment: Edge should have support for let / const variable declarations, see here: https://caniuse.com/#search=let so there might be something else going on.

Comment: it won't work in IE (seriously, who still uses that??), but this should definitely work in Edge

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are referencing `i` directly in your functions that you are binding to your Buttons. `i` will actually continue to exist even after you bound all your events, and its value will be the last value of the iteration `10`. So whenever a click function runs, it looks up `i` and finds the last value you set (`10`) and takes that value. What you want to do is add a constant reference instead - so that you bind that value you have during the loop and keep that reference forever, no matter how `i` might change later.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const localValue = i
    buttons[i].onclick = function()
    {
        counter += localValue;
        counterElement.innerHTML = counter
    };
}
```

I created a small example fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/4k8cds9n/ if you run this you should see the buttons in action. Some related reading for this topic would be around scopes in javascript, one good article: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript